# Twitter Storm's Testing API won't initialize

Tags: java, unit-testing, clojure, apache-storm

I discovered backtype.storm.Testing while reading [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549265/testing-storm-bolts-and-spouts) and got excited, but I haven't been able to get it to work because when I actually go to run the tests (from Java), the testing class won't load.

I wanted to use the functions from Testing exhibited in [xumingming's TestingApiDemo](https://github.com/xumingming/storm-lib/blob/master/src/jvm/storm/TestingApiDemo.java), but when I actually run the tests I'm getting an ExceptionInInitializerError followed by a bunch of NoClassDefFoundErrors because it couldn't initialize backtype.storm.Testing.

What's going wrong with Testing? There's no problem at compile-time. My best guess is that it needs something from Clojure which is being dynamically loaded at runtime. Has anyone else seen this?

Here's most of the relevant stack trace:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)
        at backtype.storm.zookeeper$loading__4784__auto__.invoke(zookeeper.clj:1
)
        at backtype.storm.zookeeper__init.load(Unknown Source)
        at backtype.storm.zookeeper__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
        at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2056)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:419)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:400)
        at clojure.core$load$fn__4890.invoke(core.clj:5415)
        at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5414)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5227)
        at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5264)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:603)
        at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5302)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:603)
        at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5381)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at backtype.storm.cluster$loading__4784__auto__.invoke(cluster.clj:1)
        at backtype.storm.cluster__init.load(Unknown Source)
        at backtype.storm.cluster__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
        at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2056)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:419)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:400)
        at clojure.core$load$fn__4890.invoke(core.clj:5415)
        at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5414)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5227)
        at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5264)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:603)
        at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5302)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:603)
        at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5381)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at backtype.storm.daemon.nimbus__init.load(Unknown Source)
        at backtype.storm.daemon.nimbus__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
        at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2056)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:419)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:400)
        at clojure.core$load$fn__4890.invoke(core.clj:5415)
        at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5414)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5227)
        at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5264)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:603)
        at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5302)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:603)
        at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5381)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at backtype.storm.testing$loading__4784__auto__.invoke(testing.clj:1)
        at backtype.storm.testing__init.load(Unknown Source)
        at backtype.storm.testing__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
        at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2056)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:419)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:400)
        at clojure.core$load$fn__4890.invoke(core.clj:5415)
        at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5414)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5227)
        at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5264)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:603)
        at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5302)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:605)
        at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5392)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at backtype.storm.LocalCluster$loading__4784__auto__.invoke(LocalCluster
.clj:1)
        at backtype.storm.LocalCluster__init.load(Unknown Source)
        at backtype.storm.LocalCluster__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
        at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2056)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:419)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:400)
        at clojure.core$load$fn__4890.invoke(core.clj:5415)
        at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5414)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:415)
        at backtype.storm.LocalCluster.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)
        at backtype.storm.testing4j$loading__4784__auto__.invoke(testing4j.clj:1
)
        at backtype.storm.testing4j__init.load(Unknown Source)
        at backtype.storm.testing4j__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
        at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2056)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:419)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:400)
        at clojure.core$load$fn__4890.invoke(core.clj:5415)
        at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5414)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:415)
        at backtype.storm.Testing.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at my.package.storm.bolts.MockTupleHelpers.testTuple(MockTupleHelpers.ja
va:69)
```

Update: [I found the place](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/blob/0.8.2/src/clj/backtype/storm/testing4j.clj) where I think the Testing class is being generated using Clojure. Perhaps the version of the Clojure libraries being used by my project (1.4) don't supply some necessary type in here? I'm using Storm 0.8.2.

Thanks,

-Daniel

Answer (score 3):

When you see NoClassDefFoundErrors, you are either missing some jar file in your classpath or the class isn't initialized due to some missing dependency. Check which jar files contain the classes which are throwing NoClassDefFoundError and add that to classpath.

Comment: The NoClassDefFoundErrors aren't the problem. The class that's not being found is backtype.storm.Testing, which is in the classpath, but won't initialize. The above trace is the only clue I have as to what's missing from Testing's initialization.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem using apache-storm-0.9.1-incubating. I believe the issue for us was a compilation issue we had where we were bring in zookeeper 3.4.5 while storm <= 0.9.1 is using zookeeper 3.3.3 which has a non-passive change between them. Using the a snapshot of master (0.9.2-incubating-SNAPSHOT) fixed the issue for us.