# With Storm Spouts, when is declareOutputFields( ) called?

Tags: lifecycle, apache-storm

I would like to know when the various methods on a Storm Spout are called.

I've looked at [`ISpout` javadoc](http://storm.incubator.apache.org/apidocs/backtype/storm/spout/ISpout.html), and that gives me the following mental model:

```
"instantiated" -- open(...) -----> "activated"
"activated"    -- deactivate() --> "deactivated"
"deactivated"  -- activate() ----> "activated"
"activated"    -- close() -------> "shutdown"
"deactivated"  -- close() -------> "shutdown"
```

But I am not sure when `IComponent.declareOutputFields(...)` is called. Before or after `open(...)`? When do the output streams and fields need to get declared? Within `declareOutputFields(...)`? Or it is OK to keep a reference to the `OutputFieldsDeclarer` and define them later on? If so, can it be on a separate thread?

I found this related question ([Testing Storm Bolts and Spouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549265/testing-storm-bolts-and-spouts)), but the answers don't seem to point at any design principle or specification.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The method `IComponent.declareOutputFields(...)` is called on the client machine when the client code calls `createTopology()` on the TopologyBuilder instance. Please look at the line 226 in the [TopologyBuilder.java](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/blob/moved-to-apache/storm-core/src/jvm/backtype/storm/topology/TopologyBuilder.java#L226) where this method gets called on the Spout or Bolt component(s).

The callback method `IComponent.declareOutputFields(...)` is part of the topology life cycle rather part of the Spout or Bolt life cycle. To answer your question, this method gets called before `open()` method.

The output fields should be declared in the `declareOutputFields()` method so that Storm serializes the Spout/Bolt object(s) including the configurations and output fields. The serialized instances of Spout/Bolt are then submitted to the Storm cluster after which the other life cycle methods (`activate()`, `open()`, etc.) of Spout/Bolt are called.